# Flair with a lot of badges wraps to a new line

Tags: bug, design, flair

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51927178/4885801) by [PaxDiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) and noticed that their flair had a newline in it:

[image: screenshot of flair on two lines]

I have no idea if this is a bug or not, but it kinda looks wrong to me. For fun, I changed all badge counts to `9999` and the `user-info user-hover` `<div>` that wraps the whole thing needs a width of `210px` instead of `200px`.

[image: screenshot of flair on one line]